# SQL запрос для переписки на сайте

Tags: php, sql

Имеется таблица messages в БД. Структура следующая:

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `ID_message` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ID_user` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ID_user_to` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `is_read_at` datetime default NULL,
  `text` text,
PRIMARY KEY  (`ID_message`)
)
```

Требуется получить для текущего пользователя всю последнюю переписку. Допусти Id пользователя, который зашёл в "Мои сообщения" = 5. В Базе данных имеется 5 записей с таким id:

ID_user = 5 ID_user_to = 2  created_at = 01.01.2000
ID_user = 5 ID_user_to = 2  created_at = 02.01.2000
ID_user = 3 ID_user_to = 5  created_at = 01.01.2000
ID_user = 2 ID_user_to = 5  created_at = 03.01.2000
ID_user = 5 ID_user_to = 3  created_at = 07.01.2000

Значит пользователь должен увидеть две строки:
Переписка с пользователем ID=3 Последнее сообщение: 07.01.2000, текст сообщения
Переписка с пользователем ID=2 Последнее сообщение: 03.01.2000, текст сообщения

Я сделал запрос:

```
SELECT ID_user,ID_user_to, MAX(created_at)
FROM `message`
WHERE ID_user = 5 OR ID_user_to = 5
GROUP BY ID_user,ID_user_to
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

В этом примере он вернёт строки :

ID_user = 5 ID_user_to = 3  created_at = 07.01.2000
ID_user = 2 ID_user_to = 5  created_at = 03.01.2000
ID_user = 5 ID_user_to = 2  created_at = 02.01.2000
ID_user = 3 ID_user_to = 5  created_at = 01.01.2000

Как сделать так, чтобы вместо этого он выводил:
ID_user = 5 ID_user_to = 3  created_at = 07.01.2000
ID_user = 2 ID_user_to = 5  created_at = 03.01.2000  ?

Ведь  сообщения от id=5 для id=2 и от id=2 для id=5 относятся к одной и той же переписке.

Comment: может быть вы позволите привести ваш вопрос к нормальному виду?

Comment: Так лучше?

Answer (score 2):

1. Приведите всю структуру таблицы.
2. Задайте точно и кратко вопрос - а лучше еще приведите кусок данных в таблице и что вы хотите получить в результате запроса.

Ведь сообщения от id=5 для id=2 и от id=2 для id=5 относятся к одной и той же переписке.  -вот этого я и ждал от вас. Вам нужно сделать еще одно поле - которое будет указывать принадлежность сообщения к определенной переписки - и как только сделаете - все станет на свои места

Comment: Переделал..

Answer (score 1):

Закружилась голова пока читал вопрос) Если я все верно понял, то нужно указать в запросе

`ID_user != 5`

А теперь поправочка:

```
Значит пользователь должен увидеть две строки:
 this ->  Переписка с пользователем ID=3 Последнее сообщение: 07.01.2000, текст сообщения
 Переписка с пользователем ID=2 Последнее сообщение: 03.01.2000, текст сообщения
```

И

```
Как сделать так, чтобы вместо этого он выводил:
 and this ->  ID_user = 5 ID_user_to = 3 created_at = 07.01.2000
 ID_user = 2 ID_user_to = 5 created_at = 03.01.2000 ?
```

В ходе вопроса вы указываете в двух местах разные ID в желаемом результате, что очень путает читающего вопрос!

Comment: Вы не так поняли, наверное. ID_user - автор, ID_user_to - адресат.

ID_user = 5 ID_user_to = 3 created_at = 07.01.2000 - это будет последнее сообщение переписки с пользователем 3

 ID_user = 2 ID_user_to = 5 created_at = 03.01.2000 - это будет последнее сообщение переписки с пользователем 2

Последнее сообщение моей переписки с другим пользователем может быть как входящим для меня, так и исходящим...